# code first migration add one to many relationship

Tags: entity-framework, one-to-many, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I currently have a "server" entity, defined as such :

```
public class EntityServer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I wanted to add a new "Host" entity, defined as such :

```
public class EntityHost
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PublicIP { get; set; }

    private ICollection<EntityServer> _servers;
    public virtual ICollection<EntityServer> Servers
    {
        get { return _servers ?? (_servers = new HashSet<EntityServer>()); }
        set { _servers = value; }
    }
}
```

So i added

```
public virtual EntityHost Host { get; set; }
```

to my server entity to link those entities with a one to many relationship

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityHost>()
  .HasMany<EntityServer>(x => x.Servers)
  .WithRequired(x => x.Host);
```

And generated a migration acordingly :

```
public partial class MultiHosts : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.EntityHosts",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Name = c.String(),
                    PublicIP = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        AddColumn("dbo.EntityServers", "Host_Id", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
        CreateIndex("dbo.EntityServers", "Host_Id");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.EntityServers", "Host_Id", "dbo.EntityHosts", "Id", cascadeDelete: true);
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.EntityServers", "Host_Id", "dbo.EntityHosts");
        DropIndex("dbo.EntityServers", new[] { "Host_Id" });
        DropColumn("dbo.EntityServers", "Host_Id");
        DropTable("dbo.EntityHosts");
    }
}
```

I've got some troubble setting a code first migration to add all it together as it outpout me a foreign key violation error when i try to access the context (which i understand as the server entity isn't linked to a host, as required by the model, because the hosts table is empty and I can't access the hosts entities to add one because of the FK violation ....)

So, my question is : how should I insert a default host entites for the existings server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a trick you could first set the `Server` as `Optional`

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityHost>()
  .HasOptional(x=>x.Server)
  .WitMany(x => x.Hosts);
```

Run

```
Add-Migrations set_server_optional
update-Database
```

Update your Database and then change the `Server` as `Required`

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityHost>()
  .HasRequired(x=>x.Server)
  .WithMany(x => x.Hosts);
```

And finally

```
Add-Migrations set_server_required
update-Database
```

Comment: Yeah, good idea, altrought, my problem is my application use the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion initialiser and must support updating the db and creating a new one. So this solution could be working on if i can specify some data in some kind of inter migration seed method, but i don't see any ...

Comment: no, it will work, because if the database is creating, there is no "server" entry yet so the foreigny key can't fail,  my bad